# Why is behavior different with respect to global variables in "import module" vs "from module import * "?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's have **a.py** be:

```
def foo():
    global spam
    spam = 42
    return 'this'
```

At a console, if I simply `import a`, things make sense to me:

```
>>> import a
>>> a.foo()
'this'
>>> a.spam
42
```

However, if I do the less popular thing and...

```
>>> from a import *
>>> foo()
'this'
>>> spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'spam' is not defined
>>> a.spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I've read opinions about why people don't like "`from module import *` " from a namespace perspective, but I can't find anything on this behavior, and frankly I figured out that this was the issue I was having by accident.

Comment: `globals` defined in `a.py` are going to be global in that module itself, so it is not going to define a global variable where you're importing it. Check `foo.__globals__`.

Comment: [Each module has its own private symbol table, which is used as the global symbol table by all functions defined in the module...](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you ask for `a.spam` there happens a namespace search in the module `a` and `spam` is found. But when you ask for just `spam`:

```
>>> from a import *  # imported foo, spam doesn't exist yet
>>> foo()
```

`spam` is created in the *namespace* a (you cannot access it with such import though), but not in the current module. And it seems like nobody promised us to add newly added globals of `a` to all the namespaces module `a` has been imported into via `*`. That will require storing import links inside the interpreter and probably will degrade performance if one heavily imported module does such tricks all the time.

And imagine you have defined `spam` in your main module prior to calling `foo()`. That would be downright name collision.

Just as illustration, you can do `from a import *` to get fresh updates for the module `a`:

```
from a import *
print(foo())
from a import *
print(spam)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's go thorough it step by step:

At the point of importing, `a` only has the symbol `foo` which refers to a function.

Only if the function is executed, `a` gets the additional symbol `spam`.

In the first case, you do `import a` and get a "handle" to the module, which allows you to monitor whatever happens later. If you'd do `a.spam` before calling `a.foo()`, you'd get an error.

In the second case, `from a import *` gives you whatever *currently* is in the module - and that's just `spam()`. After calling that, you could do `from a import *` to get `spam` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with Vovanrock2002.

As was recently explained to me, the '.' is a scope resolution operator. `import a` and `from a import *` give you different syntaxes. `from a import *` imports each global variable from `a` separately, and binds them as variables in the local scope. A more practical example might be the difference between `import datetime` and `from datetime import date`. With the former, I have to create a date object using `datetime.date(2015, 11, 12)`, with the latter I get to just use `date(2015, 11, 12)`.

You can read more on the [import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)

I would have to differ with you, however, in that I don't believe that spam is the meaning of life, the universe, and everything.

Comment: Calling spam _or_ a.spam doesn't work in the second case. And I agree, the world would be a sad place if spam were truely the answer.